# Separate 2xN array into M 'completely filled' arrays

Tags: matlab, math, integer, octave

I'm using Matlab/Octave, I have an array of X/Y Indices (2xM array of integers). I need to find a way to separate this array into as many other arrays as necessary so that each array is 'complete'. 'Complete' meaning that all possible combinations of X/Y exist in the array. I effectively have an integer lattice, and points scattered all around this lattice, but in a relatively patterned way. [See here for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFUIf.png). I've drafted up some tools to help visualize the data. The red lines are the lattice that has been identified in the original data, the green dots are the data points. I need to partition the data off so that each subset would produce a completely filled lattice, with a point at every intersection of the 'sub-lattice'. Partitioning them in this way would mean that any empty intersection in the original data is really an intersection between two of the fundamental sub-lattices.

For example:

Say my input array is [1 1; 1 3; 1 5; 2 2; 2 4; 2 6; 3 1; 3 3; 3 5; 4 2; 4 4; 4 6]

The output should be 2 arrays: [1 1; 1 3; 1 5; 3 1; 3 3; 3 5] and [2 2; 2 4; 2 6; 4 2; 4 4; 4 6]

If an X value of '1' is present in the array, it should be present in pairs with all Y values that show up in the array, and vice versa.

I'm aware that a unique solution isn't guaranteed for all inputs, but any solution found (outside of doing something trivial like putting each point in its own array), is useful.

Comment: I've done some more researching and think I can reformulate this as a biclique covering problem. I still don't quite know how to compute the biclique covering of this data set so if anyone has any insight please let me know. I know I'd make each possible X index and each Y index a vertex, and each coordinate pair in the original data would be an edge of the bipartite graph.

Comment: if the input would be `[1 3; 3 4; 2 6]` so the output should be [1 3;3 4] and [2 6] because [1 3] and [3 4] both have a 3 . Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, the first and second element are unique so in your example it would actually split it into three separate arrays. We'd need to expand your example a bit to make it more instructive. Notice my example above. From the input, the possible X values are 1, 2, 3, and 4. The possible Y values are 1,2,3,4,5,6. The algorithm splits the array into two arrays, where in the first array holds Xs of 1 and 3, and Y values of 1 3 and 5, and holds every possible combination of these values.

Comment: It is helpful if you edit your question and  provide more explanation and provide simple illustrative example

Comment: Thank you rahnema, I discovered the following paper which outlines my exact problem, and proposes the algorithm I need in section 4. http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~bein/pubs/biclique.pdf

Comment: I suggest that you change title of the question to "How to implement Biclique Partition Problem" and state what you have tried so far may you receive more responses